# My message wont show on my textbox?

Tags: c#

I am trying to fill a form (Movie information such as Title, Year and Genre) and then show it in a textbox (enable=false).
I have 2 classes and a Form (with 2 textboxes (for user input), 2 buttons, 1 to register the movie infos, and 1 to show the infos in a 3rd textbox (the one that is Disabled).

```
class Movies
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }

        public string ReturnMovie()
        {
            return Title + " (" + Year.ToString() + ")";
        }
    }

class Genres
    {
        public string Genre { get; set; }

        public string ReturnGenre()
        {
            return Genre;
        }
    }
```

**MainForm:**

```
        bool btnRegisterClicked = false;

        Movies m1 = new Movies();
        Genres g1 = new Genres();

        private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnRegisterClicked = true;

            if (btnRegisterClicked == true)
            {
                if (txtTitle.Text.Length == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Enter a title for the movie.");

                    btnRegisterClicked = false;
                }

                else if (txtYear.Text.Length < 4)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid year.");

                    btnRegisterClicked = false;
                }

                else if (chkGenre.SelectedIndex == -1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Select the genre(s) of the movie.");

                    btnRegisterClicked = false;
                }

                else
                {
                    txtTitle.Text = m1.Title;
                    txtYear.Text = m1.Year.ToString();
                    chkGenre.Text = g1.Genre;
                }

                txtTitle.Clear();
                txtYear.Clear();
                chkGenre.ClearSelected();
            }
        }

        private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtShow.Text = m1.ReturnMovie() + g1.ReturnGenre();
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What isn't working? Please be specific.

Comment: `bool btnRegisterClicked` seems redundant

Comment: If you want the textbox 3 to remain unmodified, set the IsReadOnly to true. Making IsEnabled to false will not allow any value from being set.

Answer (score 5):

The assignments in your `else` block are backwards.  You're setting the `TextBox` to the un-initalized contents of `m1` and `g1`, and then immediately `.Clear()`ing them out.

```
else
{
    m1.Title = txtTitle.Text;
    m1.Year = int.Parse(txtYear.Text);
    g1.Genre = chkGenre.Text
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign values to variables not to controls..., change following

```
        else
        {
            txtTitle.Text = m1.Title;
            txtYear.Text = m1.Year.ToString();
            chkGenre.Text = g1.Genre;
        }
```

to

```
        else
        {
            m1.Title = txtTitle.Text;
            m1.Year = int.Parse(txtYear.Text);
            g1.Genre = chkGenre.Text;
        }
```